# Is there a way to specifically target a shared drive when copying a file to a shared google drive using google drive-drive-api-v3 and node js

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-docs

I am trying to upload a google doc to a shared drive using the drive API v3 via nodejs. The user doing the upload has write and edit permissions on the folder being targeted to copy the file to, and all the OAuth has been set up etc... However, I get the following error:

```
   domain: 'global',
   reason: 'notFound',
   message: 'File not found: 1BPRlu4tWhsjsRp8tjQKL59o5apWkPa0k.',
   locationType: 'parameter',
   location: 'fileId' } ] }
```

Is there a way to target the shared drive specifically?

```
function listFiles(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
  drive.files.list({
    q: "mimeType = 'application/msword'",
    pageSize: 100,
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const files = res.data.files;
    if (files.length) {
      console.log('Files:');
      files.map((file) => {
        console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
        drive.files.copy({
          fileId: file.id,
          'name' : 'Updated File Name',
          'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'
          'parents': ['1BPRlu4tWhsjsRp8tjQKL59o5apWkPa0k']
        })
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No files found.');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: 1BPRlu4tWhsjsRp8tjQKL59o5apWkPa0k  <-- is not a valid directory that the user has access to.   Do a file.get on it make sure the user has access to that directory.

Answer (score 1):

According to v3 standards it's better to use the resource item to store the request body parameters. Using the supportsAllDrives flag you can specify to target both personal and shared drives. In this way you will be able to target the folders ids in your shared drive as well. Now the parameter is false by default, please mind that *This parameter will only be effective until June 1, 2020. Afterwards all applications are assumed to support shared drives.*

```
let resource = {
  'name' : 'Updated File Name',
  parents: ['1BPRlu4tWhsjsRp8tjQKL59o5apWkPa0k']
}
drive.files.copy({
    fileId: file.id,
    supportsAllDrives: true,
    resource: resource
});
```

### References:

[Files copy docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alessandro.

To actually get this working I needed to add quite a few extra parameters including driveId, corpora, includeItemsFromAllDrives and supportsAllDrives. Note: supportsAllDrives is soon to be deprecated (June 2020).

In the end it looked a little bit like this...

```
function listFiles(auth) {

  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});

  let resource = {
    name: 'Copied File Shared to Shared',
    parents: ['xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx']. //folder to upload to on Shared Drive
  }

  drive.files.copy({
    fileId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', //file to be copied
    driveId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
    corpora: 'drive',
    supportsAllDrives: true,
    resource: resource
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const files = res.data.files;
    console.log("Success!!!")
  });
}
```